# Outlook Addin Updating - Replacing DLL sufficient?

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

Working on an outlook addin and I was wondering if manually replacing the compiled DLL on a target machine is sufficient when I decide to update my addin ? is that practice even valid for stability ?

on some minor changes i did to my addin for tests, It seemed to work, even without changing the manifest, or re-deploying but I'm not sure it will still work if the project changes from end to end - Like, is it possible to take a whole different addin dll, and simply place it instead of a dll that is already installed - and walla ? does its manifest even acknowledge the content of the dll or simply point to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is sufficient when I decide to update my addin ? is that practice even valid for stability ?

Theoritically, you can replace the add-in assembly with a new one. But the host application should be closed at that time to let you delete/overwrite an existing file. Be aware, the Trust center settings in Outlook can be adjusted to load only signed with a digital signature assemblies. In that case your add-in will not be loaded by the host applications.

Consider using ClickOnce for updating add-ins on the fly. See [Deploying an Office Solution by Using ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772100.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as you do not change the addin's class name.